# how do I upload a photo to facebook from my app, and have it NOT post to the wall?

Tags: image, facebook, upload, graph

My iPhone app uploads pictures to the user's Facebook account, and they are automatically placed in the app's photo album on Facebook.

In the majority case, the user's wall is also automatically updated to denote that the photo was recently updated.  But I dont want this, because I prefer to make a separate wall post with a link to the photo.  It's silly for the user's wall to have two entries on it with a thumbnail of the same image.

1) how can I upload the photo using the graph API in such a way that it isn't announced on the user's wall

2) how can I tell if the photo upload resulted in an announcement on the user's wall -- sometimes it doesn't.  I'd rather not have to ask for permissions to read the user's wall..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) Facebook Doc:

> If you would like to suppress the story that is automatically generated in the user's feed when you publish a photo (usually because you plan on generating your own), you can add a no_story=1 parameter. In this case, the user will receive a notification that your application has uploaded a photo.

Comment: I can't find the no_story parameter referenced there, but can on a more general page - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/482/